# What does relationship owner means in bidirectional relationship?

Tags: hibernate

I have a simple model with a `Question` and `Choice` object.

- ONE Question has MANY CHOICE(S).
- MANY Choice has ONE Question

There are two ways to implement that with Hibernate

**Implementation One: The owner side is Choice**

Question.java

```
@OneToMany (mappedBy="question")
private Set choices = new HashSet();
```

Choice.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn (name="QUESTION_ID")
private Question question;
```

**Implementation Two: The owner side is Question**

Question.java

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn (name = "QUESTION_ID")
private Set choices = new HashSet();
```

Choice.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn (name="QUESTION_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private Question question;
```

What is the difference between the two implementation?

Comment: Prove me wrong, but I believe changing the non-owning side only is not reflected in the database automatically (using dirty checking), while modifying owning side without modifying the other *is*. Note that in this case the *many-* side is the natural choice for owner since it has foreign key on the database level.

Comment: Didn't you forget to put the type argument in the Set of choices? E.G : Set<Choice> choises. If you don't use it, how hibernate can determinate where (what class?) to find the "question" attribute that you are referring to in the mappedBy annotation.. or hibernate is self aware of that somehow.. or i don't know how this is working behind the curtains..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your first example is normal and correct bidirectional one-to-many/many-to-one mapping. Setting `Question` to `Choice`-attribute ("owning side") is enough to have relationship persisted. Entity graph in memory will be messed until other side of the relationship is read from database again. From the
database point-of-view owner is the entity that is persisted to table that have foreign key column (same for bidirectional one-to-one). In specification this is explained following way:

> The many side of one-to-many / many-to-one bidirectional relationships
>   must be the owning side, hence the mappedBy element cannot be
>   specified on the ManyToOne annotation.
>   ....
>   Bidirectional
>   relationships between managed entities will be persisted based on
>   references held by the owning side of the relationship. It is the
>   developer’s responsibility to keep the in-memory references held on
>   the owning side and those held on the inverse side consistent with
>   each other when they change. In the case of unidirectional one-to-one
>   and one-to-many relationships, it is the developer’s responsibility to
>   insure that the semantics of the relationships are adhered to.

In JPA terms your second example does not have owning side, because of absence of `mappedBy`. Instead you have two unidirectional relationships which are forced to use same column as store. At least with Hibernate 3.5.6 it will behave following way:

- Setting `Question` to `choice`-attribute will not persist relationship.
- Adding `Choice` to `question`-attribute will not persist relationship.
- To persist value to `"QUESTION_ID"` both have to be set (yes, also not-`insertable` `question`).

Answer (score 1):

Bidirectional relationships must follow these rules:

1. The inverse side must refer to its owning sideby using the mappedBy attribute
2. The owning side may have the inversedBy attribute
3. @ManyToOne is always the owning side of a bidirectional association
4. @OneToMany is always the inverse side of a bidirectional association
5. the owning side of a @OneToOne association is the entity with the table containing the foreign key
6. The many side of many-to-one bidirectional relationships must not define the mappedBy attribute
7. For many-to-many bidirectional relationships, either side may be the owning side

Comment: Does not help in clarifying the doubt in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to remember that without `mappedBy` you will run into an issue of *circular dependencies*. This happens when there is no owner in a bidirectional relationship.

In a circular dependency you will (explicitly) set both sides of the entities before saving

```
thisObj.set(thatObj);
thatObj.set(thisObj);
```