# Should @JoinTable be specified in both sides of a @ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, entity-relationship

I've an entity `Course` and an entity `User`. There's a *many-to-many* relationship between course and user, since a course can have many users and a user can be enrolled in many courses. In both entities I've put the `@ManyToMany` annotation on the specific field, that is, in `Course` I have:

```
@ManyToMany
private List<RegisteredUser> members;
```

and in `User` I have:

```
@ManyToMany
private List<Course> coursesTaken;
```

Now, I know that this kind of many-to-many relationships are usually represented by a third table. I also know that there's the annotation `@JoinTable` which allows us to do that. What I don't know is if I should add this annotation `@JoinTable` over both fields in the two different entities or not. By the way, if I need to add to both, the names need to match right?

Comment: I hope this makes it clear for you: https://github.com/iuliana/many-to-many .  You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 22):

It's actually a good question, and it helps to understand the concept of an "owning" entity because neither side needs a `@JoinTable` annotation. If you want to prevent both sides from having `join tables`, a good idea, then you need to have a `mappedBy=` element on one side. The `@JoinTable` annotation is used to either specify the table name, or the columns that map the association.

First look at the [Javadoc for @JoinTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html):

> Specifies the mapping of associations. It is applied to the owning side of an association.

Whether or not there is a `join table` is controlled by the `mappedBy="name"` element of the `@ManyToMany` annotation. The [Javadoc for mappedBy for the `ManyToMany` annotation says](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html#mappedBy--):

> The field that owns the relationship. Required unless the relationship is unidirectional.

For your (bidirectional) example in Hibernate (5.0.9.Final), if there were only two `@ManyToMany` annotations and no `mappedBy=` element, the default will have two `Entity` tables and two `Join Tables`:

```
Hibernate: create table Course (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Course_Member (Course_id bigint not null, members_id bigint not null, primary key (Course_id, members_id))
Hibernate: create table Member (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Member_Course (Member_id bigint not null, courses_id bigint not null, primary key (Member_id, courses_id))
```

While this is saying that each Entity "owns" its `ManyToMany` relationship, the extra `join table` is redundant in the typical use case. However, if I decide to have the `Member` entity "own" the relationship, then I add the `mappedBy=` element to the `Course` entity to specify that it doesn't own the relationship:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="courses")
Set<Member> members;
```

Adding `@JoinTable(name="Member_Course")` to the `Member` entity doesn't change anything: it's only naming the table the same as it would have been named anyway.

Since the `Course` entity no longer owns its `ManyToMany` relationship, the extra `JoinTable` will not be created:

```
Hibernate: create table Course (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Member (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Member_Course (members_id bigint not null, courses_id bigint not null, primary key (members_id, courses_id))
```

This is important to the developer because he or she must understand that no relationship is persisted unless it's added to the owning entity, in this case the `Member` entity. However, since this a bidirectional relationship, the developer should be adding **both** a `Course` to `Member.courses` and a `Member` to `Course.members` anyway.

So, if you have a `bidirectional` `ManyToMany` relationship, which means you have `ManyToMany` on both entities involved, then you should add a `mappedBy="name"` on one of them to avoid having a redundant `join table`. Since it's bidirectional, I don't think it matters which side you make the `owning` entity. As always, it's always a good idea to enable the sql logs and see what's going on in the database:

References:

[What is the difference between Unidirectional and Bidirectional associations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360795/what-is-the-difference-between-unidirectional-and-bidirectional-associations).

[What does relationship owner means in bidirectional relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931342/what-does-relationship-owner-means-in-bidirectional-relationship).

[What is the “owning side” in an ORM mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749689/what-is-the-owning-side-in-an-orm-mapping).

[Most efficient way to prevent an infinite recursion in toString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300203/most-efficient-way-to-prevent-an-infinite-recursion-in-tostring).

Answer (score 14):

**You actually CAN use @JoinTable on both sides** and often it makes perfect sense! I am talking out of experience after I had been looking for this solution for weeks.

Even though all throughout the internet, blogs and articles tell a different story - and the Javadoc of JPA is easily misunderstood (or wrong) in this way. I tried it after seeing this uncommented example in a book for professionals - and it worked.

**How to do it:**

Singer-Instrument-Association:
**Singer side**:

```
@ManyToMany 
@JoinTable(name = "singer_instrument", joinColumns =
@JoinColumn(name = "SINGER_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "INSTRUMENT_ID")) 
public Set<Instrument> instruments;
```

And exactly the same on the other side!
**Instrument side**:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "singer_instrument",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "INSTRUMENT_ID"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SINGER_ID"))
public Set<Singer> singers;
```

So, if you address the same join table, "singer_instrument", with the same name, it work's. 
If you address one join table "singer_instrument" and one join table "instrument-singer" though, it will indead result in two different join tables in the database.

This makes a lot of sense, because a many-to-many relationship has **no** owning side - seen from the database perspective. Owning side means the side, that owns the **foreign key** of the relationship. But neither the table "singer" nor "instrument" have a foreign key referring to each other. The foreign keys are inside the neccessary **join table** between them.

The **advantage of @JoinTable on both sides** of the relation:
Let's say, a singer starts to learn a new instrument: You can add the instrument to singer (and vise versa, as it is bidirectional) and update/merge the singer. The update will **update only the singer and the join table. It *won't touch* the instrument-table**.

Now the other case - a guitar-course has ended, so you want to remove the connection between the guitar and the former course-participants/singers: After removing the instrument "guitar" from the singers (and vise versa!), you update/merge the instrument. The update will **update only the instrument *and the join table*. It *won't touch* the singer-table**.

If you had @JoinTable only on one side, you would always have to update/save/delete *this side* to safely handle the entries in the join table (the relationships between singers and instruments). In this case, you would have to update *each* singer, who ended the guitar course. That is **not reflecting the type of relationship properly** and can cause **performance issues** and **conflicts during data transaction**.

Comment: This is possible though the @JoinTable should not be used like this, refer to the [documentation](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_2-mrel-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1617267436_3edd264198c2d080caae57372599aaca) at `11.1.27 JoinTable Annotation`  : 
 > A JoinTable annotation is specified on the owning side of the association.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Both sides get `@ManyToMany`, but only one has the `@JoinTable`

[More ManyToMany info here](http://blog.jbaysolutions.com/2012/12/17/jpa-2-relationships-many-to-many/)

Answer (score 0):

For `@ManyToMany` to work on an an existing schema (not made by Hibernate) you will have to use the @JoinTable annotation on both classes to specify the table and which columns map to Java member variables in the appropriate class. I think this example may help you with what properties should be passed to the annotation:

https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-using-annotations-1.html